# How to get the value after a certain word in the column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

[image]

How can I get just the `Phone Number` and `Key` value from `column-A` from the table, so that I can use those `Phone Number` and `Key` values and filter in another table?

**Result:**
Phone Number=998767700
Key=34567

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL Server 2016 you can use `string_split` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) to separate the key/value pairs in your string. Then you can use XML syntax to extract keys and values:

```
declare @test table (id int, columnA varchar(100))

insert into @test select 1, 'Name = john;Phone Number=998767700;amount=90; Key=34567'

;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT  
         [Id]
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(value, '=', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    from 
        @test
            cross apply 
        string_split(columna,';') 
    where 
           ltrim(value) like 'Phone Number%'
        or ltrim(value) like 'Key%'
    )
SELECT 
     [Id]
    ,ltrim(rtrim(Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(100)'))) AS [key]
    ,ltrim(rtrim(Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(100)'))) AS [value]
FROM Splitted;
```

Result:

[image]

PS Please consider changing the structure of your table to a normalized one